# Errors when I try to access a return array from a method

Tags: c#, arrays

when I try this, I got the error:
name cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

So I thought the reason are the static field name / static method:

```
class  cars
{
    public static string name;
    public cars()
    {
    }
    public  static cars[] get_cars()
    cars[] cars = new cars[2];
    for (int k = 0; k < cars.Length; k++)
    {
        cars[k] = new carss();
        name = "Car 0" + k;
    }
    return cars;
}
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    cars[] cars = new cars[2];
    cars = cars.get_cars();
    cars[0] = new cars();
    set_label_header(cars[0].name);
    cars[1] = new cars();
    set_label_header(cars[1].name);
}
```

Then I tried it with non static method und get a new error message.

An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method

```
class  cars
{
    public  string name;
    public cars()
    {
    }
    public   cars[] get_cars()
    cars[] cars = new cars[2];
    for (int k = 0; k < cars.Length; k++)
    {
        cars[k] = new carss();
        name = "Car 0" + k;
    }
    return cars;   
}
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    cars[] cars = new cars[2];
    cars = cars.get_cars();
    cars[0] = new cars();
    set_label_header(cars[0].name);
    cars[1] = new cars();
    set_label_header(cars[1].name);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This code does not compile and is poorly-formatted. Please update with code that at least compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very confusing, because both the class name and variable name is `cars`. In c#, convention is to start class names with a capital letter. So the class name should be `Car`. You really can't reason about this code without making that simple fix first.

In the `InitializeComponent` method, you have this line of code:

```java
cars = cars.get_cars();
```

In this context, `cars` is an array of type `Car`. But of course, c# arrays do not define a method called `get_cars`. You need to update this line of code to reference the static method on the `Car` class instead:

```java
cars = Car.get_cars();
```

After you make that change, the static version of your `get_cars` method should work (after you fix the other compilation issues in your original code).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the opening curly brace after `get_cars()`. After that, nothing made sense to the compiler, and it struggled (and failed, as it so often does) to give you a meaningful error message. Your non-static version of the method had the same error. This method ought to be static, so we'll go with the static version.

There's another error, less obvious, that the compiler couldn't see: `name` was static. That means that there was one `name` shared among all cars, instead of each car having its own name. You would have found that when `get_cars()` returned two cars, both of them would have been named `"Car 01"`, because that would have been the last thing you assigned to the static `name` field that all of them shared.

I've fixed that, and I renamed the `car` class to `car`, since it represents only one car.

```
class car
{
    public string name;
    public car()
    {

    }
    public static car[] get_cars()
    {
        car[] cars = new car[2];
        for (int k = 0; k<cars.Length; k++)
        {
            cars[k] = new car();
            cars[k].name = "Car 0" + k;
        }
        return cars;
    }
}
```